# shell script not exiting prompt after execution

Tags: shell, unix, sh

The below code gets executed properly in vs code terminal but when I run it in windows-ubuntu shell it gets the result but never terminates the program, even when I press ctrl+q or ctrl+z or any other command.

The program takes two numbers as input and executes the command option like plus, minus, multiply and divide.  It gets the result but does not exit the code in shell prompt.  But it works fine on VS code terminal

I do not understand what else needs to be describe here, this stack flow keeps asking me to write more description.

[image]

```
#!/bin/sh
#============================================
plus()
{
    sum=$(( $1 + $2 ))
    echo "$sum"   
}
minus()
{
    minus=$(( $1 - $2 ))
    echo "$minus"   
}
multiply()
{
    multiply=$(( $1 * $2 ))
    echo "$multiply"     
}
divide()
{
    divide=$(( $1 / $2 ))
    echo "$divide"     
}
help() {
   echo "
   Description:
      Simple calculation
   Syntax:
      Calculate [-plus|-minus|-divide|-multiply] -a1 num1 -a2 num2
 
   Examples: 
      $ calculate -plus -a1 1 -a2 2
      3
"
exit 0
}

#============================================
# main program
#============================================

typeset calculate

if test $# -eq 0
then
   help
else
   a1=
   a2=
   mode=
   while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
   do
      case "$1" in
          -plus) mode="PLUS"; shift;;
          -minus) mode="MINUS"; shift;;
          -divide) mode="DIVIDE"; shift;; 
          -multiply) mode="MULTIPLY"; shift;;
          -a1) shift; num1="$1"; shift;;
          -a2) shift; num2="$1"; shift;;
          *) echo "Error in $0: wrong option $1"; help; exit 1;;     
      esac
   done
fi

tmpname=${0##*/}
# if [ $(echo $tmpname | wc -c) -gt 8 ]
# then
# typeset -L8 command=$tmpname
# else
# command=$tmpname
# fi
# Keep the first 10 characters
command=`echo "$tmpname" | sed 's/^\(..........\).*/\1/'`
TEMPA=/tmp/${command}A$$
TEMPB=/tmp/${command}B$$
ALL_TEMP="$TEMPA $TEMPB"

trap "/bin/rm -f $ALL_TEMP; exit 1" \
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 12 13 15 16 17 19 20 21
trap "/bin/rm -f $ALL_TEMP" 0

if [ "$mode" = "PLUS" ]
then
   plus $num1 $num2
elif [ "$mode" = "MINUS" ]
then
   minus $num1 $num2
elif [ "$mode" = "DIVIDE" ]
then
   divide $num1 $num2
elif [ "$mode" = "MULTIPLY" ]
then
   multiply $num1 $num2
fi
```

Comment: Start by running your script through https://shellcheck.net and implementing its suggestions.

Comment: The first line is a great hint.  Fix that.

Comment: My bash is at the correct location #!/bin/sh